# Simple & small, pure javascript lightbox (dialog overlay)?

Tags: javascript, dialog, overlay, lightbox

Does anyone know of a small, limited functionality lightbox built with pure javascript? This is for an embeddable widget, thus the reason of not using jquery. All I really need is creating an overlay for a specific div or simply by passing some HTML.

Comment: I've rolled back a couple of edits here which attempted to make this question on-topic by eliminating the off-topic request for resources. Unfortunately, the question started out being *only* a request for resources and all of the existing answers are responding to that request by giving links to resources. There is no way to change *this* question such that it's not asking for resources without invalidating the answers, which isn't permitted.

Comment: If there were already answers which provided more than just resources, the question might be able to be edited to be on-topic and, perhaps, the answers which just provided resources deleted. That's not the case here. The only way to have the question be on-topic would be to completely rewrite the question and delete all the answers. That's effectively the same as just asking a new question. So, if someone wants a question which is similar to this, but which asks how to create a lightbox, rather than asking for resources, then [ask that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a great list/comparison of lightboxes [here](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/). You can quickly scan which require a JS library (jQuery, MooTools, etc.) and which don't, and you can also see what features each supports. There's a sizable chunk of them that don't use any JS library, so you should be able to easily find one to suit your needs.

Here's a few to get you started:

- [EnlargeIt!](http://enlargeit.timos-welt.de/english/index.php)
- [Floatbox](http://randomous.com/tools/floatbox/)
- [iBox](http://www.enthropia.com/labs/ibox/)

Comment: The link to Floatbox has a certificate issue. That's the problem with answers of this nature!

Answer (score 1):

I am currently developing a light responsive Lightbox just for images, without the need for jQuery etc... and with IE8+ Support.

[You can download it here](http://jslightbox.felixhagspiel.de)

Please report any bugs or issues. Thanks!

Comment: Link only answer and the link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a more of a light weight modal dialog, and I found Zebra Dialog which uses Jquery.

http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-dialog/

Comment: Zebra is a nice drop in to mimic the various windows MessageBoxes (info, error, warning, etc).